# Emacs fails to display subscript characters (such as ₁, ₂) after upgrade to Mavericks

Tags: emacs, unicode, fonts, osx-mavericks

I've recently upgraded OS X to 10.9 Mavericks, and since this upgrade Emacs has problems with displaying unicode subscript characters (such as ₁, ₂). There are a few strange things about this behaviour:

- it doesn't seem to depend on the font, as I've tried selecting several
  different Unicode fonts;
- it doesn't seem to affect any other unicode character, as I've tried several
  uncommon mathematical operators, which display just fine. Even *superscripts* (¹,²)
  are displayed as normal;
- it doesn't affect anything outside of Emacs, as the characters are displayed by
  my browser just fine.

Does anyone have a clue what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: @lunaryorn ah, yes. I'm running `GNU Emacs 24.3.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this in the version of Emacs you are using, 24.3, and it appears to be broken. However, I also built Emacs from a recent snapshot of the Emacs trunk, which appears to be working correctly.

You can download a prebuilt version from www.emacsforosx.com under Other versions -> Nightlies, alternatively you could wait for the next Emacs release which typically comes out around this time every year.

Comment: I've installed the latest nightly version, and can confirm that the bug is indeed no longer present (though it is still present in the most recent pretest version). Thanks! :)

Comment: I tried this with the latest pretest version, Emacs-pretest-24.3.91-universal-10.6.8.dmg, and subscripted Unicode characters are working for me now too.